# How to extract data and append it into np.arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to learn how to use np.arrays, and as a practice task, I am working on a program that reads data from a file and adds it to some arrays.

The function `read_from_file()` is supposed to return some arrays that contain the sorted datapoint so that they can be plotted easily with matplot lib.

**The code I have written so far is**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_from_file(filename):

    a = np.array
    b = np.array
    c = np.array
    d = np.array


    with open(filename, "r") as infile:
        infile.readline()
        for line in infile:
            infile.readline()
            delta_x = float(line[9:21].strip())
            approx = float(line[34:50].strip())
            abs_error = float(line[91:103].strip())
            relative_error = float(line[121:133].strip())
            n_ = int(line[137:].strip())

            a = np.append(delta_x)
            b = np.append(approx)
            c = np.append(abs_error)
            d = np.array(relative_error)

    return a, b, c, d

test = read_from_file("datafile.txt")
```

**The datafile I'm trying to read from looks like this** (I only care about every other line)

```
0.1 0.045590188541076104
delta_x: 1.000000e-01, df_approx: 4.5590188541e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.409811e-02,           rel_error: 8.819623e-02, n=1
0.01 0.00495661575773676
delta_x: 1.000000e-02, df_approx: 4.9566157577e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.338424e-03,           rel_error: 8.676848e-03, n=2
...................................
delta_x: 1.000000e-18, df_approx: 0.0000000000e+00, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 5.000000e-01,           rel_error: 1.000000e+00, n=18
1e-19 0.0
delta_x: 1.000000e-19, df_approx: 0.0000000000e+00, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 5.000000e-01,           rel_error: 1.000000e+00, n=19
```

**My problem is**
I think I am managing to extract the data as intended (tested it out on lists etc). But when I try to add this to the np.arrays it gives me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/(...).py", line 55, in <module>
    test = read_from_file("datafile.txt")
  File "C:/(...).py", line 48, in read_from_file
    a = np.append(delta_x)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in append
TypeError: _append_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is there anyone out there kind enough to provide me with a solution to this problem?
2. How can I add data to np.arrays (kind of like how you do with lists)
3. What is the best way of adding data to np.arrays
4. If I want to use a for-loop to iterate through an array (kind of like how you would do it with lists), what is the best way to do it?

All help is much welcomed and highly appreciated

Comment: Do not treat arrays like lists.  That gets you into a lot problems.

Comment: Did you spend any time reading the `numpy for absolute beginners` documentation?

Comment: `np.append` docs says twice that it returns a **copy**, unlike list append which works in-place.  The correct thing is to build the list, and make an array from that.

Comment: @hpaulj: Tank you for your feedback. I have now updated my code with the improvements and suggestions you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When learning to use `numpy`, you need to have the `numpy` documentation at hand, and take time to read the basics, and the help for each function that you use.  Don't naively treat arrays "like lists".

```
def read_from_file(filename):

a = np.array
```

`np.array` is a function.  Why are you assigning that to an variable?  Arrays are created with expressions like `a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`.  Reread the `np.array` docs.

```
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    infile.readline()
    for line in infile:
        infile.readline()
        delta_x = float(line[9:21].strip())
        ...

        a = np.append(delta_x)
```

`np.append` docs says it makes a copy from TWO inputs,

```
In [239]: x =np.append(np.array([1,2,3]), 4)
In [240]: x
Out[240]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

It does not operate in-place like list append.  The `np.append` docs try to make this clear.  The only thing that would be clearer would be delete the function entirely!

```
In [241]: x=[1,2,3]
In [242]: x.append(4)
In [243]: x
Out[243]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you must build an array iteratively, stick with lists until the end

a = []
for _ in loop:
a.append(values)
arr = np.array(a)

numpy arrays can be faster than lists if they are used correctly, as documented.  They are not faster if used *like lists*.  If anything they are slower, and often don't even work.

I suspect your file can be read with `np.genfromtxt`, using the version of `delimiter` that specifies column widths.

```
delimiter : str, int, or sequence, optional
The string used to separate values.  By default, any consecutive
whitespaces act as delimiter.  An integer or sequence of integers
can also be provided as width(s) of each field.
```

Speaking of `genfromtxt`, that function reads a file line by line, collecting results in a list of lists (one sublist per line).  It then makes the 2d array from the result at the end.  It does not try to build arrays incrementally like lists.

Answer (score 1):

1. To create an empty numpy array (when you don't know the final shape), you should use `np.array([])`
2. [`np.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) takes two arguments: the array to append to, and the values you want to append. You only pass one.
3. [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) over the file so you can only parse the lines you actually need.

Try:

```
def read_from_file(filename):
    a = np.array([])
    b = np.array([])
    c = np.array([])
    d = np.array([])
    
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for i, line in enumerate(infile):
            if i%2 == 0:
                continue
            contents = line.split(", ")
            values = [c.split(":")[-1].strip() for c in contents]
            a = np.append(a, float(values[0]))
            b = np.append(b, float(values[1]))
            c = np.append(c, float(values[2]))
            d = np.append(d, float(values[3]))
    return a,b,c,d

a, b, c, d = read_from_file("file.txt")

>>> a
array([1.e-01, 1.e-02, 1.e-18, 1.e-19])

>>> b
array([0.45590189, 0.49566158, 0.        , 0.        ])

>>> c
array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

>>> d
array([0.04409811, 0.00433842, 0.5       , 0.5       ])
```

Comment: while your code may work, it encourages bad practices.

Comment: @hpaulj: I don't have any doubts. This is probably not clean code by any means. But keep in mind that I am a beginner who is just learning about arrays. This task is for the sake of learning and getting familiar with using arrays in a "learning by doing sort of way". However, with that being said, if you would be kind enough to show me a solution that would be considered good practice, I would be very grateful:-)

Comment: There have been many posts about the bad uses of `np.append`.  It is not a list append clone, and shouldn't be used as such.

Comment: @not_speshal: Thank you for helping me out and providing me with a working piece of code that I can learn from. Cheers.

Comment: @hpaulj: Sure. point taken. Thanks for the feedback. I hope you find the time to show me what a good practice solution would be. That would be very helpful.